# AADSTS50001: The application named X was not found in the tenant named Y while authenticating Postman in Azure AD

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, postman, azure-service-fabric

I have an Azure based web application (developed with Service Fabric framework) and when I am trying to access the token required for authorization, I am getting a below error message

> AADSTS50001: The application named https://b2bxxx.com/ was not found in the tenant named xxx-xxx-xxx-Xxx-xxxx

[image: Please refer the AD authentication used in Postman]

Could some one please look provide a fix to this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Rakesh.
I've been banging my head against a wall with this issue for the last couple of days.
Consent must be granted by an Azure AD Global Admin which I assume you aren't. have a look at https://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-admin-consent/
Hope this sheds some light on the issue.